# Wordpress messing with my db calls on the wordpress pages?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hey, hows it going everyone? I am having database conflicts I was wanting some help with.

Basically, I have a header that pulls in a random database field. Nothing special. It is in my header in my template and works just fine on non WordPress pages.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM headerslogans ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $myrow['slogan'];
};
```

I am using the same database, same user name, same password, etc. However, I get this error where the echo should be....

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in <dir name>
```

So obviously the wordpress connection is "overwriting" the other (wordpress works flawlessly). BUT, I was also confused as to why it doesn't work, although it is connecting to the same database with same username and password.

Can anybody help me out on this?

**UPDATE: Posted connection code**

$x = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass,true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$x);

Comment: You have this code in your header.php file? If so, you should _not_ be doing that

Comment: This kind of code should go in a plugin or at least your functions.php.

Comment: I see what you mean. But I need this code to work on OTHER parts of the site that are NOT wordpress driven. This code is in a sitewide inc-header.php include file. Included everywhere, not just wordpress.

Comment: Can you post your mysql connection code? That's where the problem lies, not in the sql statement.

Comment: @Ciaran - Sure. Thanks! Like I said, this works fine on NON-Wordpress pages. Thanks for the help!

$x = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass,true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$x);

Comment: Are all of your variables set? The error message you are getting indicates that there is no username or password set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the connection is getting overwritten, is the database selection also getting over written? It's probable that actually `mysql_select_db()` is the thing screwing you over. Fix it by setting you your original connection as a variable, and referencing it in the offending mysql_* functions, eg:

```
$dbcnct = mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db('...', $dbcnct);
mysql_query('...', $dbcnct);
```

This shouldn't affect your current setup either.

Comment: You can specify a database directly in the queries: `SELECT fieldname FROM database.table ...`. Selecting a default database just removes the need from specifying the database name explicitly.

Comment: Exactly, this will plug in to OPs current setup without having to change all the queries...

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I have tried that. I now get "Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in <dirname>", ONLY on the wordpress pages.

Comment: You need to include the mysql_connect on the pages that use your own mysql_query...

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Well... that worked.... unfortunately. If I declare everything every single time, right before the SQL statement, it works. Which means I have to put the dbname, user, login, etc etc every single time I want to pull data from it.  Grrrrr!! :)  Surely there is another way? *sniff sniff*   Thanks again!

Comment: There should be no need to do that, simply declare the connection to a variable (`$dbcnct` in my example) then put that variable as the second parameter in your mysql_query, eg `mysql_query($sql, $dbcnct);`, it will use the connection defined in `$dbcnct` to do the query.

Comment: I SOOO wish I could say it is working, but its just... not.. Here is the code: $xconnect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$xconnect);    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM headerslogans ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysql_query($sql2,$xconnect);
 while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $myrow['slogan'];

Comment: FYI, the error is: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in

Comment: Are you declaring it or using it inside a function? Because if so you will need to declare it `global`.

Comment: Forgive my noob ignorance on that one. What you see is my entire code. It really isn't part of a function I guess. Are you talking about declaring it globally for wordpress or just... in general? Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

@NarfFlarf: You could just use WordPress queries to get your data --

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM headerslogans ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($myrow as $result) {
    echo $myrow->slogan;
}
```

See [this WordPress Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#SELECT_Generic_Results) for further reference.

**Update**

Something else you can perhaps try then is to have `<img src="slogan.php" alt="">` and within `slogan.php`:

```
<?php
/* Instantiate own, non-WP MySQL connection */
/* Run query and retrieve image */

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/' . $image); // 'dynamic' image!
?>
```

Comment: Hmmmm good idea! Let me throw this wrench in the machine though.  I have code EVERYWHERE, on lots of different pages, that makes calls the traditional way to the database.  I am really really trying to avoid changing all of those, especially since I am not that proficient with php and mysql connectivity yet.

Comment: @NarfFlarf: See my updated answer which _might_ mean less modification to your existing code.

Comment: I agree with @stealthyninja to use the wpdb object. I believe you also have to add the following at the top of your file: <?php global $wpdb; ?>